ACL2 compile single book on command line
How do you compile a book on the command line using ACL2? I'm looking for something akin to coqc for Coq.

Consider the following book
;; file: factorial.lisp
(in-package "ACL2-FACTORIAL")

(defun positive-integer-p (x) (and (integerp x) (>= x 0)))

(defun factorial (x) (cond ((= x 0) 1) ((positive-integer-p x) (* x (factorial (1- x))))))

If you copy-paste it into the REPL acl2 with a defpkg preamble, the definitions are accepted. However, this isn't great for batch-mode interactions.
The recommendation adapted from the book tour is somewhat verbose. We manually create a package and then call a function certify-book, all from within the acl2 repo.
(defpkg "ACL2-FACTORIAL"
  (union-eq *common-lisp-symbols-from-main-lisp-package*
            *acl2-exports*))

(certify-book "factorial" 1 t)

I know there's a cert.pl script but it isn't bundled with the debian acl2 distribution and it handles a lot of stuff. I only really need to handle the single-book case for now.

cert.pl is the usual command-line tool to certify ACL2 books.
I would suggest building ACL2 yourself instead of getting a release from your package manager. Those versions tend to be old and, as you found out, do not contain as much as the repository.
For installing ACL2, see https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/acl2/current/HTML/installation/installation.html and https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/acl2/manuals/latest/index.html?topic=ACL2____BUILDING-ACL2.

Oh, interesting, it doesn't support clisp. It's also interesting that the installation page doesn't mention GNU Common Lisp, even though that's the lisp implementation that the Debian package uses.

There is a doc page about GCL: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Emoore/acl2/manuals/latest/index.html?topic=ACL2____GCL.
I'd suggest CCL or SBCL.

The method used by the acl2 standard library is to put the build instructions for different books in files ending with the .acl2 extension.
Here is set-theory.acl2 which describes how to build the book set-theory.lisp.
ACL2 appears to use cert.pl to bootstrap itself, but it's straightforward enough to use the same trick that cert.pl does in the makefiles that it generates.
Basically, whenever you have a .acl2 file, you can compile it by doing something similar to this in a makefile:
%.output : %.acl2
        acl2 < $^ > $@
        # grep for error messages in $@

This seems like a pretty good solution, but I'm not sure how robust it is. ACL2 is very chatty and I'm not sure how to reliably detect whether an error was generated or not.

This shell script works for tiny examples, but there's a more scalable solution used in the ACL2 repo itself.
I couldn't figure out the right way to do this, so I've been using the following script to check a simple book (always producing a fresh certificate) and then exit.
It just automates the commands in the book tour by writing them to a [file].acl2 if it doesn't already exist and then reading that file into acl2 on stdin.
#!/bin/sh
# compile-acl2 [file] (with or without without lisp extension)
# naively compile a single book with no dependencies.

die() {
  printf '%s\n' "$@" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

f="$1"
test -n "$f" || die 'no file'
f="${f%.lisp}"
test -f "${f}.lisp" || die "${f}.lisp does not exist"

# Conservatively assume that all of these files are out of date.
# I don't know how to get ACL2 to exit differently depending on whether
# the certify command was successful or not, so instead we will
# remove everything that a successful run could have produced
# beforehand and check for it immediately after running acl2.
#
# Don't delete "$f".acl2 though. Maybe we generated it, maybe we didn't.
rm -f -- "$f".cert "$f".port "$f".lisp.port "$f".o  "$f".debug_output

uc_f="$(printf '%s\n' "$f" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')" || die 'cannot translate name to uppercase'

if ! test -f "${f}.acl2"; then
    cat <<EOFEOF 1> "$f".acl2 || die 'cannot write to file'
;; -*- mode: acl2; -*-
(defpkg "ACL2-${uc_f}"
  (union-eq *common-lisp-symbols-from-main-lisp-package*
            *acl2-exports*))

(certify-book "$f" 1 t)
EOFEOF
fi

acl2 0<"${f}.acl2" 1>"${f}.debug_output"

if test -f "${f}.cert"; then
  exit 0
else
  cat 0<"$f".debug_output 1>&2
  die "failed to compile file: output recorded in $f.debug_output"
fi

